# Creating a template that can fill multiple .docx and .pdf files using Office

Tags: microsoft-word, pdf, microsoft-office, adobe-acrobat, forms

I repeatedly have to fill out multiple documents with the same information (name, first day of work, etc.) Some of these documents are Word documents and some are PDFs. I am wondering if there is a way within Office or Adobe Acrobat DC to create a template where I only have to enter the information once and it will populate multiple documents with this information.

Currently, I use a template I created in Word where I have all of the information that I need marked (ie [FIRST NAME] and I can use "Find/Replace" to replace every  instance of [FIRST NAME] with the person's first name. This works great for my Word docs, but I still have to enter all of the information into my PDFs one by one.

I tried importing the PDFs into my Word Template, and inserting [FIRST NAME] where I need it, except when I publish the PDF from that page, I can't publish fillable fields. These documents need to be added to and filled by other people in the organization.

I must use either Office or Adobe, and the final PDFs can't loose any functionality. Is there a way to do this?

Any suggestions?

Thanks!

Comment: Your question is very unclear. Do you mean that you want to generate from Word a PDF that has fillable fields?

Comment: Adobe Acrobat has the capability to author PDF forms.  Why can't you use that?  You must know that questions, seeking software recommendations, are not considered to be within scope.

Comment: Okay, sorry about the clarity issue, let me try again:

Comment: I've re-worded the question, hopefully it makes sense now. Thanks!

Comment: The thing is, with current pdf conversion methods, nothing you do in Word is going to give you a fillable pdf form. This is not all that surprising given that Word has multiple methods, some incompatible, of producing forms.

Comment: Okay, that makes sense. I was hoping if I created text boxes or something in the original word doc, there was a way of exporting them as fillable. Thanks for your response!